# Data not being written in csv

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

Im using the following code to populate csv

```
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))

f.writerow(["user_id", "male", "female", "less15", "sixteen", "twentysix", 
            "thirtysix", "fortysixplus", "happy","neutral", "surprise"])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        x = json.loads(createjson(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
        print(x)

        for row in x:
            print(row)
            f.writerow([row['user_id'], row['male'], row['female'], row['less15'], 
                        row['sixteen'], row['twentysix'], row['thirtysix'], 
                        row['fortysixplus'], row['happy'], row['neutral'], row['surprise']])
```

print(x) prints the following

> [{'fortysixplus': 8, 'surprise': 11, 'female': 3, 'twentysix': 6,
>   'male': 2, 'user_id': 1, 'less15': 4, 'sixteen': 5, 'thirtysix': 7,
>   'neutral': 10, 'happy': 9}] {'fortysixplus': 8, 'surprise': 11,
>   'female': 3, 'twentysix': 6, 'male': 2, 'user_id': 1, 'less15': 4,
>   'sixteen': 5, 'thirtysix': 7, 'neutral': 10, 'happy': 9}

however the data is not being written in csv. why so?

**UPDATE:**
I tried using dictwriter as follows,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        x = json.loads(createjson(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))


        for row in x:
            print(row)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f = open('test.csv', 'w'), fieldnames=row.keys)
            # writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(row)
```

but still im getting the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/R&D/Documents/Maxis_2/Maxis/src/dwell_time_maxis.py", line 128, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 146, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

Comment: looks like your row isn't a list, but a dictionary.

Comment: how do I write those elements to csv?

Comment: Your original code looks like it should work.  It isn't a complete example, but what is likely happening is you didn't close the file so it didn't flush to disk.  `DictWriter` is a more simple solution, so I've added an example as an answer.

Comment: What does `print(row)` in your original code output? Your output of `print(x)` does not look like an `Iterable` but rather as a string that was once a strange combination of a dict in a list, and a dict. Try replacing with `for row in x[0]:`. `csv.writerow` immediately flushes to disk so that's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @bluppfisk `csv.writerow` does not immediately flush to disk. That would crater performance.

Comment: I just ran it and it writes just fine without me having to close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `DictWriter` example using your sample data and Python 3.  Note the correct way to open a file for use with the `csv` module is to use the `newline=''` parameter.  `fieldnames` is a required parameter when opening a `DictWriter` so the class instance knows what column names you want and in what order.

`x` is a list of dictionaries.  `writerows` will write each dictionary as a line in the output file in one shot.  You could also use `for row in x: w.writerow(row)` to write one line at a time.

```
x = [{'fortysixplus': 8, 'surprise': 11, 'female': 3, 'twentysix': 6,
      'male': 2, 'user_id': 1, 'less15': 4, 'sixteen': 5, 'thirtysix': 7,
      'neutral': 10, 'happy': 9}]

with open('test.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames='user_id male female less15 sixteen twentysix thirtysix fortysixplus happy neutral surprise'.split())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(x)
```